# Scraping a site with Beautiful Soup: trying to find a div element with specific id returns None

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
import csv

# adding a correct user agent
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
#The url to be scraped
company_page = 'https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/6.Best_Books_of_the_20th_Century?'

#opening the page
page_request = request.Request(company_page, headers=headers)
page = request.urlopen(page_request)

#parse the html using beautiful soup
html_content = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#Parsing some of the title elements
title = html_content.find('div',id='shell')
print(title)
```

Comment: which information you refer to it by `id="shell"`?

Comment: If your matter is solved please mark an answer as accepted so that others can see that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to retrieve all book titles:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
company_page = 'http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/6.Best_Books_of_the_20th_Century?'

page = requests.get(company_page, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

titles = soup.find_all('a', class_="bookTitle")
for title in titles:
    print(title.text)
```

Output:

```
To Kill a Mockingbird
1984
Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone (Harry Potter, #1)
The Great Gatsby
Animal Farm
The Hobbit, or There and Back Again
The Diary of a Young Girl
The Little Prince
Fahrenheit 451
The Catcher in the Rye
The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe (Chronicles of Narnia, #1)
The Grapes of Wrath
One Hundred Years of Solitude
...
```

A detail: Be aware that I have changed `urllib` to `requests`.